# CakePHP select database based on subdomain

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, subdomain

I am setting up a website that I would like to have different databases for a licensed user.

The users will access their page via a subdomain. I would like this subdomain to choose the database to use.

e.g.
Client A db name = clienta

URL = www.clienta.website.com

This should tell CakePHP to select the database with name clienta

I am using CakePHP 2.x

Any advice would be excellent!!

Thanks

Comment: Use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have 'database' => param in $default()

Instead in database.php:

```
function __construct() {
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $host = str_replace("www.", "", $host);   //remove www part
    $host = str_replace(".website.com", "", $host);

    $this->default["database"] = $host;
}
```